# Question on finding the algebraic integers of a quadratic number field

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I’m following this [lecture](https://youtu.be/IHCF76mlnlU?si=Zmk7D6eh1qO5C4Jg) which is part of a course on Galois theory by Richard Borcherds. This question concerns the section on computing the algebraic integers of a Quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ where $n$ is square-free (which starts at time 19:17). So the section starts by assuming that $a+b\sqrt{n}=\alpha\in Q(\sqrt{n})$ is an algebraic integer, and then gets to the point that $Tr(\alpha)=2a$,$N(\alpha)=a^2-b^2n\in \mathbb{Z}$. That makes sense because both of them are rational algebraic integers, and therefore they are integers. Then the case where neither $a$ nor $b$ are integers is considered. Since $2a$ is an integer then $a$ is the sum of an integer and a half. With some symbolic manipulation, $4b^2n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then he says

> And since $b$ is square-free this implies that $2b$ is also an integer.

That doesn’t make a lot of sense to me because I thought square-free-ness was a property of integers (or maybe he’s using an obvious definition of square-free-ness of rationals: both the denominator and the numerator are square-free when the fraction is reduced, but even so, how do we know that $b$ is square-free?). Maybe there’s a mistake and he meant $n$ is square-free, but even so, why does that imply that $2b\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: This is a typo, he means "since $n$ is squarefree." Consider a prime dividing the denominator of $2b$, if it isn't an integer; how many times can that prime divide $n$?

Comment: Set $c=2b$ and write $c=\frac{x}{y}$ for integers $x,y$ such that $\gcd(x,y)=1$. If $c$ is not an integer, then  $y\neq 1$ and $y$ factors as powers $k_i$ of primes $p_i$.  Since $y\perp x$ then $y^2\perp x^2$. Hence, each prime of $y^2$ divides $n$ (since $c^2n$ is an integer). But each prime divides it once since $n$ is square free, so if we denote by $j$ the product of the primes of $y$, $y^2/j\neq 1$ is coprime to $n/j$, and also coprime to $x^2$ which means that $y^2/j$ is coprime to $x^2(n/j)$. So that means that $c^2n$ is not an integer. A contradiction. So $y=1$. Is that correct?